# CKEditor to Kohana3

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, ckeditor, kohana-3

How to connect a text editor (WYSIWYG) [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) to Kohana3. Can the details, every little thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my [Editor](http://github.com/biakaveron/editor) module.